# Powershell SSH difficulty entering passphrase

Tags: powershell

I have a server I connect to via SSH, and I used ssh-keygen to generate an RSA key-pair, I have my server configured such that I can only login via SSH, and I have a passphrase for the key-pair. On initial setup/configuration, I was able to login with the key-pair, paste the passphrase in (using right-click) when prompted, and then successfully SSH into my server using Powershell.

Ever since that initial run through, I have had strange difficulties actually entering the key-pair passphrase in Powershell. When I SSH to my server, I get the passphrase prompt and it **will not work** if I type the passphrase manually. It also will not work through most normal methods of copy-paste into Powershell. The only way I can get it to accept a Passphrase entry is to right click the Powershell menu bar and go to Properties, and set the option Ctrl+Shift+C/V for Copy/Paste. With that option enabled, I can use that technique (and no other) to paste in the passphrase. This seems..very strange to me that no normal Powershell copy/paste scenarios work otherwise and that I **cannot even type the passphrase manually.** I am not a regular Powershell user, so I'm wondering if maybe there's something really obvious I'm missing when I type the phrase in manually (I just hit enter after, expecting it to work--it does not.)

Note that once I enable Ctrl+Shift+C/V for copy/paste, I can then **copy and paste normally** in the SSH session, using right click to paste (which is more comfortable to me due to muscle memory.)

Is there any way to get Powershell to behave in a more normal way with entering or pasting in a passphrase?

Comment: What's the command you run? The one thing I can think of here is a keyboard mismatch of some sort, something like having the numlock on on a keyboard of a different language

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is probably not with PowerShell, but with the SSH utility
that you use.
It apparently uses Ctrl+Shift+C/V for Copy/Paste and not the Windows
standard Ctrl+C/V.
PowerShell may be blocking this key combination for some reason
(but do try it without changing anything in PowerShell).

Your difficulties with typing the passphrase are less clear to me.
It's possible that this SSH utility is just not echoing your password.
Some Linux-oriented products do this as a security measure.
So you might be truly typing without knowing that you do.

For more information, please specify the SSH utility used here.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted you. However, I am using Powershell as my SSH client, sorry if that was not clear in my post. There is no other SSH utility involved, I enter: ssh actname@ipaddress and Powershell opens an SSH session inside Powershell itself.

Comment: There is no difference - there's only one built-in SSH client in Windows 10.